# How to model a non-standard oval shape

Tags: modeling

I'm pretty new to modeling and I'm creating a 3d model of the Mandalorian helmet just for fun. I started creating the oval base, cut it in half (for mirroring it later), then I went up by extruding and scaling constraining on the X axis first and then on the Y axis, because the helmet has a non-standard oval shape. After closing the whole thing I realized that the edges, due to the X-Y scaling, are all zigzaggy and I don't like it.

[image]

Reference:
[image]

How can I fix this?

I'm using 2.79b

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question and include the reference images you are using. It may be difficult to help without seeing what you are trying to make.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys done, thanks. it seems a normal bowl but actually it's not, changes in curves are very subtle but they're there...

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have a part that is completely messed up, Select it and delete:

[image]

Select the borders and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill*:

[image]
[image]

Play with the parameters in the *Operator* box (on the bottom left of your 3D view) to fill properly (here: *Span* 3, *Offset* -2):

[image]

Comment: That didn't work. In your example, the outer edges are straight and so the one created with fill grid "copies" from that and that's ok. But all of my lines are zigzaggy and the tool doesn't work when I delete too many vertices

Comment: so make sure that the outer edge is rounder. Maybe share your file to give a try: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/